# Serve both static and apis in express in production

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, vue.js

I have deployed a express/vue app to production.
I'm finding a bit difficult to serve both static files and APIs from express.

Inside expressfolder/app.js

```
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const serveStatic = require('serve-static')

...

// index.html and static/css, static/js - bundle made with npm run build
const DIR_DIST = path.join(__dirname, '../../path/to/dist')
app.use(serveStatic(DIR_DIST))

...

app.get('/tests', (req, res) => {
  res.send({msg: 'Hello there!'})
})
```

- When i go to myapp.com, I see the index.html as desired.
- If I type directly in the browser myapp.com/tests I see the raw msg "hello there" from express.
- If i call the same route via the link inside index.html, I receive this error in chrome

> (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

It's working on my local machine, so I'm sure it's some kind of messy config I haven't set properly.

Also, I don't want to be able to access `/tests` directly: vue-router should override that, but it's a lesser problem.

It's probably been asked before, but it's been a while and I haven't found a solution yet.
Thanks.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is a networking failure (probably not the code you're showing us).  You'd have to show us exactly what request was being sent and the context in which it was sent from for us to have any idea how to help.  For example, what does this mean: "If i call the same route via the link inside index.html".  Can you show us the exact link you're using?

Comment: Also, there is no need to use `serve-static`.  Express has [`express.static()`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) built right in.

Comment: To not be able to access `/tests` from the URL bar in the browser, you will probably have to provide some special custom header on the http request that is required from your API (and can be added for an Ajax call), but will not naturally be present when typed into the browser and then your API will need to test for that special header and return either a 400 error (bad request) or a 401 error (unauthorized) or do a 307 temporary redirect to one of your web pages.

Comment: @jfriend00 your first comment pointed me in the right direction. I had this bad boy inside axios configs: `baseURL: "http://localhost:8081"`

Comment: I'm learning express right now and may have used some outdated tutorial for that serveStatic: working late at night has its downsides. As for the API routes that shouldn't be accessible directly, it's just from a UX point of view, not related with security.
I will just change `/test` to something like `/api/version/test`
Thanks.

Comment: Since you have now solved your own question, you can either delete it or you can write your own answer.  Please do one or the other so it doesn't just sit here empty with no answers.

Comment: I'd either close it or you can write an answer since it was your knoledge that solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is a fundamental networking error that occurs before your server code actually gets to run so that would likely have nothing to do with your specific server code.

It probably happens because you have a bad URL in your web page.